# Count based user and ip address

Tags: python, arrays, shell

I've file like this

```
USER_ID,IP_ADDRESS
XXXXXX24,10.12.6.54
XXXXXX24,10.12.6.54
XXXXXX24,10.12.6.54
XXXXXX24,10.12.6.54
XXXXXX24,10.12.6.54
XXXXXX25,10.12.6.55
XXXXXX25,10.12.6.55
XXXXXX25,10.12.6.55
XXXXXX25,10.12.6.55
XXXXXX25,10.12.6.55
XXXXXX21,10.12.6.51
XXXXXX21,10.12.6.51
XXXXXX21,10.12.6.51
XXXXXX21,10.12.6.51
```

I need an output with counts based on IP address
Like

```
10.12.6.51 10.12.6.55 10.12.6.54
XXXXXX21      4
XXXXXX25                 4
XXXXXX24                            4
```

So this is the code and its fine and I'm getting the output like this. I need more detail on the output.

```
#!/bin/python3.6

import csv
import collections
datafile=open('conn.csv','r')
usefuldata=[]
for line in datafile:
   usefuldata.append(line)
from collections import Counter
outfile1=Counter(usefuldata)
print(outfile1)
```

And finally with the help of Barmer I was able to come up with the following output

```
Counter({'XXXXXX24,10.12.6.54\n': 5, 'XXXXXX25,10.12.6.55\n': 5, 'XXXXXX21,10.12.6.51\n': 4, 'XXXXXX24,10.12.6.56\n': 3, 'USER_ID,IP_ADDRESS\n': 1})
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [help/on-topic] and [ask].

Comment: Use `Collections.counter()`

Comment: `cat conn.py
#!/bin/python3.6

import csv
import collections
datafile=open('conn.csv','r')
usefuldata=[]
for line in datafile:
   usefuldata.append(line)
from collections import Counter
outfile1=Counter((line[0])  for line in usefuldata)
print(outfile1)
# ./conn.py
Counter({'X': 14, 'U': 1})` @Barmar I've given you the script I wrote and the output. However I'm getting only the first letter for the user-id not sure how to get the complete user-id . Also could you please help on the count based on the ip-address as well. Thank you

Comment: Put code in the question, not a comment

Comment: You're not using `csv` in that code, so `line[0]` is the first character of the line. Also, you shouldn't be counting just the first field, since you want separate counts for each IP.

Comment: You just want `Counter(datafile)`

Comment: @Barmar Thank you so much for your help. So finally I shall I remove those \n and the word counter. So getting into a formatting part. I tried editing the .csv file with notepad++ to remove all blank spaces. I'm not able to get rid of \n

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `pandas` along with `collections.Counter`

For example:

```
import collections

import pandas as pd
from tabulate import tabulate

with open("data_file.csv") as file:
    next(file, None)  # skip the header
    counter = collections.Counter([line.strip() for line in file])

output = collections.defaultdict(dict)
for user_and_ip, ip_to_user_count in counter.items():
    user, ip = user_and_ip.split(",")
    output[ip].update({user: ip_to_user_count})

df = pd.DataFrame(output).fillna("")
print(tabulate(df, headers="keys"))
df.to_csv("user_to_ip.csv")
```

Output:

```
          10.12.6.54    10.12.6.55    10.12.6.51
--------  ------------  ------------  ------------
XXXXXX24  5.0
XXXXXX25                5.0
XXXXXX21                              4.0
```

And the `.csv` file:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/python3.6

import csv
import collections
datafile=open('conn.csv','r')
usefuldata=[]
for line in datafile:
   usefuldata.append(line)
from collections import Counter
outfile1=Counter(usefuldata)
#print(outfile1.most_common())
for value,count in outfile1.most_common():
  print(value,count)
```

I was able to achieve what I want by above code

```
[root@lhqsb1db2db01 Scripts]# ./conn.py
XXXXXX24,10.12.6.54
 5
XXXXXX25,10.12.6.55
 5
XXXXXX21,10.12.6.51
 4
XXXXXX24,10.12.6.56
 3
```